# Добавление элементов внутрь каждого блока, который является тэгом "TR"

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно выбрать каждый tr и добавить в него еще один td

```js
var z = document.createElement('tr');
z.innerHTML = row;
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0] += document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild(z);
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<!-- пробывал так: но не выходит. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так.

```js
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
// Only tbody tr
var tr = tbody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  var z = document.createElement('td');
  z.textContent = 'row ' + i;
  tr[i] += tr[i].appendChild(z);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <table class="table table-stripedrin">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>sss</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>eee</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>ttt</td>
        <td>333</td>
        <td>555</td>
        <td>999</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>999</td>
        <td>444</td>
        <td>333</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>222</td>
        <td>888</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>zzz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- пробывал так: но не выходит. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (tr of document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr')) {
  tr.insertCell(1).textContent = 'second';  // добавить в указанную позицию
  tr.insertCell().textContent  = 'last';    // добавить в конец
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #aaa1; }
td { padding: 0.2em 0.5em; min-width: 2em; border: 1px solid #ccc; font: 16px sans-serif; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```